# QGIS PDF Export Atlas only Raster, no selectable Text

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, atlas

i have a huge QGIS Project with loads of WFS, WMS and all sorts of shapes. In the layout, there are also Pictures and a Logo included (.jpeg). Also there are a lot of legends and text fields. I am using the atlas function. In some of the text fields I have links.

Now when i export to PDF via the Atlas export OR the normal Export, all the layers in the Atlas file are exported as rasters, including all texts. Now since I have links in there, i would like to have at least the text fields selectable (copy past the link into your browser).
When I set up a new file the export is working as expected and i can select the text and different layers. Is there another - hidden - setting that i can somehow change? I tried both of the most recent version (stable / experimental).
I have already tried a lot of things, maybe someone can help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on export to PDF from Atlas toolbar, a warning message (*Composite Effects*) will popup that recommends to print the layout as raster. At the bottom left corner of the message uncheck `Print as raster`.

If the warning message didn't show, go to layout tab and uncheck `Print as raster`, then when you export as PDF from Atlas toolbar the warning message will appear, and from there disable the option to `Print as raster`. The output pdf files will make the text selectable.

[image]

Comment: so easy! thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer is correct and I'm glad it's works fine for you. My precision here this is don't work if you use transparency...! Because if you use vector technology, then transparency disappears.